# How to Fetch Multiple Types From CloudKit using CKRecord.ID?

Tags: swift, cloudkit

When fetching multiple types from `CloudKit` using `CKRecord.ID` I get the following error.

**Error**

```
Cannot invoke 'map' with an argument list of type '(@escaping (CKRecord.ID, String, CKAsset, Int) -> Lib)'
```

**CloudKit Fetch Function**

```
static func fetch(_ recordID: [CKRecord.ID], completion: @escaping (Result<[Lib], Error>) -> ()) {
    let recordID: [CKRecord.ID] = recordID
    let operation = CKFetchRecordsOperation(recordIDs: recordID)
    operation.qualityOfService = .utility

    operation.fetchRecordsCompletionBlock = { (record, err) in
        guard let record = record?.values.map(Lib.init) ?? [] //returns error here
        else {
            if let err = err {
                completion(.failure(err))
            }
            return
        }

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            completion(.success(record))
        }
    }

    CKContainer.default().publicCloudDatabase.add(operation)
}
```

**Lib**

```
struct Lib {
    var recordID: CKRecord.ID
    var name: String
    var asset: CKAsset
    var rating: Int
}
```

How can I retrieve multiple types from `CloudKit` using the `CKRecord.ID`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer from @Jessey was very helpful but kept returning a `fatalError()`. What ended up working was adding to the `init`.

**Lib**

```
struct Lib {
    var recordID: CKRecord.ID
    var name: String
    var asset: CKAsset
    var rating: Int

    init(record: CKRecord){
        recordID = record.recordID
        name = (record["name"] as? String)!
        asset = (record["asset"] as? CKAsset)!
        rating = (record["rating"] as? Int)!
    }
}
```

The "name", "asset", and "rating" are the custom field names in CloudKit dashboard records. I also got rid of the `?? []` in the `fetch` function per the instruction.

[CloudKit Tutorial: Getting Started](http://CloudKit%20Tutorial:%20Getting%20Started) was a good reference.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't defined an initializer that accepts a `CKRecord`.

This will make it compile:

```swift
extension Lib {
  init(_: CKRecord) { fatalError() }
}
```

Get rid of your `?? []` and go from there!

It may help you if you use accurate pluralization:

```swift
operation.fetchRecordsCompletionBlock = { records, error in
  guard let libs = records?.values.map(Lib.init)
```